# What's the meaning of http protocol fields in Wireshark?

Tags: http, networking, https, wireshark

what's the meaning of below field in http response?

```
 Vary: Accept-Encoding,Accept-Encoding\r\n
.......
....
 Content-encoded entity body (gzip): 20108 bytes -> 91914 bytes
(if this line means the size of data after compress, why the compress size is bigger than initial size?)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These are HTTP headers - the headers specify size of data, MIME types, compression, ...

For details, check https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_header_fields